# Do "those who came before" transcend time?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

In the Assassin's Creed 2 games (particular the first and last ones), when "those who came before" speak it's implied that they are talking to Desmond rather Ezio.

Since Desmond is using the Animus to relive Ezio's memories he can't actually change the past, this being said how did "those who came before" know Desmond was reliving Ezio's memories, were they actually talking to him in real time or did they calculate the future.

Comment: AC 4 talks about that subject, and I think they calculated probabilities, and tought that desmond was the one who had the highest probability of success. But still, it doesnt make much sense.

Comment: The plural of "Animus" is "Animi", by the way ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is revealed in *Assassin's Creed 3*, that *those who came before* are using a device that predicts (and possibly even renders) the future.

In layman's terms, it means that:

Desmond
- is talking to a recording.

Those who came before
- are talking to the recording of a prediction.

How Juno managed to...

> manipulate Desmond into killing Lucy

...at the end of *Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood*, is unknown.